# Can't scroll list of data when map inside Stack

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, mobile

I want only header of Table calendar to show the results on monthly basis that's why is overlap the calendar till header with another column where is show list of data everything is working fine but i unable to scroll to the end of list i am trying many things but failed please help me to solve this issue

here is my code sample

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    child: Container(

      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 430,
            child: TableCalendar(
              headerVisible: true,
        
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 66.0,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              ),
            
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 45,
                    width: 430,
                    
                    child: Row(
               
                   
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 20),
                      child: Column(children: [
                        for (var i = 0; i < _events.length; i++) ...[
                          ListTile(....
                            
                        ),
                        ]
                      ])),
               
               
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, I can suggest the following option as part of your implementation:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 430,
              child: TableCalendar(
                headerVisible: true,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 45,
                    width: 430,
                    child: Row(
                      // Add your Row configuration here if necessary
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        // You can change this loop to 
                        // for (Event event in _events) ...{
                        //    ListTile(title: Text(even.name)),
                        // },
                        for (var i = 0; i < _events.length; i++) ...{
                          ListTile(title: Text('Title')),
                        }
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

The primary issue is that SingleChildScrollView does not automatically calculate the total height of its children when they're positioned within a Stack. This can lead to the scrollable area not being large enough to include all the content, especially when using Positioned widgets that take their children out of the normal document flow.

Comment: i want to use stack to overlap the table calendar to show calendar header only because i want to show events on monthly basis